# europecv with italian language selected doesn't recognize accents

Tags: font-encodings, europecv

I've found some issues with europecv documentclass. I've loaded the `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` and included latin1 and italian in the class' keyvalues, but still it doesn't recognize accents as if utf8 was not specified (but it is because europecv uses utf8 as default fontenc)..

I am using TeX Live 2014 version and this is my first question on this site.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,latin1,helvetica,narrow,italian,logo,notitle,totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}


% Define personal data
\ecvname{Salvo Montalbano}
\ecvnationality{Italiana}

\begin{document}
    \begin{europecv}
        \ecvpersonalinfo
        \ecvmothertongue[1pt]{Italiano}
        \ecvsection[5pt]{Istruzione e formazione}
        \ecvitem[1pt]{Date}{10/09/2014 -}
        \ecvitem[1pt]{Nome e tipo d'organizzazione erogatrice dell'istruzione e formazione}{\textbf{Universit\`a degli studi di Verona}}

    \end{europecv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that document class but you may have to let LaTeX know that you are using latin1 encoding using \\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}.

Comment: If you want to use `utf8`, remove the `latin1` option.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why are you specifying `latin1` to begin with? Remove it and you'll get “Università”

Comment: Thank you @egreg, @Bernard and @HerbShulz !! I didn't know that `latin1` command was about font encoding!! I've simply copied an example of documentclass... Thanks everybody and sorry, I am a beginner in this marvelous world...

Comment: @Bernard An answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[latin1]` option of europecv loads `inputenc` with the same option. So, if you want to use the default `utf8` encoding, you don't have to specify any encoding option, but have to be sure your document is saved in  UTF8 encoding — which the default of most modern editors (TeXmaker, TeXsudio, TeXworks, Winedt,&c.).